# Laravel 4 eloquent WHERE with AND and OR?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

How do I say WHERE `(a=x AND b=y)` OR `(c=z AND d=j)`

For x , y , z .. are variables .

How can i do that with eloquent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for multiple where statements use:

```
$result = Model::whereRaw('(a = ? and b=?) or (c=? and d=?)', ['x','y','z','j'])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by passing a closure into the `where()` function of the query builder. This is covered in the advanced wheres section of the docs http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres

```
$results = MyModel::where(function($query) {
        $query->where('a', 'x')
              ->where('b', 'y');
    })->orWhere(function($query) {
        $query->where('c', 'z')
              ->where('d', 'j');
    })->get();
```

Comment: From the looks of it, yes. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L557

Comment: that would be 4.2, not available in 4: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php

Comment: Should still work in 4, give it a try? https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L288

Comment: ah I see, well sadly I'm running 5.0 right now and don't have a project with 4.0 lying around, I'll take your word on it :D, it's just that I couldn't find any documentation about it earlier (before version 4.2) so wasn't sure if it would work